# Every page outputs only a page title

Tags: ee2, server-migration, blank-screen

After migration to another server, all pages stop working. Now every pages displays only a "page title". Debug is set to 1, there is no PHP errors. I want to create a 2nd enviroment on the local server (XAMPP 3.2.2), for testing a new template. Any idea why i didn't see a proper page? Where i should start to searching a problem source?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still new to EE, hence no experience with WSOD. But others have. There are a ton of approaches and potential reasons in this thread. Maybe/probably it covers yours:

[White screen of death after server move](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13739/white-screen-of-death-after-server-move)