# WSOD on index.php and system, no problem reaching phpinfo

Tags: debugging, server-migration, blank-screen

I have migrated my EE 2.5.1 install to a new dev machine (actually just OS - Ubuntu 13.10 - reinstall from scratch) and cannot get past WSOD in home or system. I checked the instructions from the [server migration guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/operations/moving.html), file permissions etc. seem to be good. Database config is good and config.php has all the same paths as previously.

I can reach phpinfo page in the same directory as index.php. I can also get to the server wizard front page, but as soon as I click "check my server" I get the WSOD again. [System requirements](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/installation/requirements.html) are good according to phpinfo.

I have absolutely no debugging info on index.php or system, regardless of debug=1 in index.php and [xdebug.scream](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1085/1235) in php.ini; the only error in Apache logs is a warning from the phpinfo page.

The only difference I can think of between this and the previous install is that I installed PHP5-cli first, before Apache2, and had to install php5-mod-apache afterwards.

How can I get past the WSOD, or at least get some more debugging info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xdebug.scream did start giving output a while later, I presume the WSOD without output was cached or something. It gave me the answer to my question: I hadn't installed php mysql drivers.

Comment: Lol, poor bastard. Hate it when this shit happens, especially when u can't charge for it.